# Wrap text within element

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap text inside a div with a span.

```
<div class="item">
   <span class="count"></span>
   Text that needs to be wrapped.
</div>

<div class="item">
   <span class="count"></span>
   Text that needs to be wrapped.
</div>

<div class="item">
   <span class="count"></span>
   Text that needs to be wrapped.
</div>
```

Tried this but it did not really work...

```
$('.item').text().wrap('<span class="new" />');
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it using [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('.item').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).contents().eq(2).wrap('<span class="new"/>')
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUUbW/

Answer (score 12):

How about

```
$('.item').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<span class="new" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/x5eFp/3/

Comment: I was about to post almost the same thing, you can optimize it by replacing `$.trim($(this).text()).length` for `$.trim(this.nodeValue) != ''`

Comment: I noticed that &nbsp; in the div was also wrapped... while @wirey's solution did not. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

**Single DIV**:

```
var txt = $('.count')[0].nextSibling;
$(txt).wrap('<span class="new" />');
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/TELV6/)

**Multiple DIVs**:

```
var markers = document.querySelectorAll('.count'),
    l = markers.length,
    i, txt;

for (i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    txt = markers[i].nextSibling;
    $(txt).wrap('<span class="new" />');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/CLfWc/1/)

Comment: Sorry, my example had a single div, there could be multiple: http://jsfiddle.net/TELV6/1/

Answer (score 3):

if you need to wrap text content inside an element use `wrapInner`

https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

example html

```
<div class="item">contents inside needs to be wrapped</div>`
```

```
// jQuery
$('.item').wrapInner('<span></span>')
```

Answer (score 2):

My take on this:

```
$('.item').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != '') {
       $(this).wrap('<span class="textwrapped"></span>');
    }
});
```

The `$.trim` part is needed as tabs used to indent html code are also text nodes that we have to filter out (eg. as the tab right before `<span class="count">` )

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/c2549)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').html($('<span class="new">').text($(".item").text()))
```

Comment: This doesn't wrap his text node inside a span.... and what is #id - he's got classes, etc. - use those.