# wrap only text inside a span

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i wrap only the content present inside the span excluding the tags..

Here is the markup what i have...

```
<span class="foo">
   <span class="bar">+</span>
   lorem ispum lorem ispumlorem ispumlorem ispum
</span>
```

now this is what i want it to be

```
<span class="foo">
  <span class="bar">+</span>
  <span class="foobar">lorem ispum lorem ispumlorem ispumlorem ispum</span>
</span>
```

`$('.foo').wrapInner('<span class="foobar"/>')` is wrapping the entire inner content.\

thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap text within element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652140/wrap-text-within-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to filter nodes and then wrap. Use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Try this:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().eq(2).wrap('<span class="foobar"/>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nu98C/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out the text nodes and wrap them:

http://jsfiddle.net/dKtD6/

```
$('.foo').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) != '';
}).wrap('<span class="foobar" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

To Wrap the content Inside Tags you can use

```
 $('.foo').wrapInner('<span class="foobar"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextSibling` to get the textNode, then just wrap it

```
$($('.bar').get(0).nextSibling).wrap('<span class="foobar" />')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9WTCW/1/)